# Partial specialization tempate c++

Tags: c++, templates, template-classes

I was exploring the JUCE framework and find this interesting code,

```
namespace SampleTypeHelpers // Internal classes needed for handling sample type classes
{
    template <typename T, bool = std::is_floating_point<T>::value>
    struct ElementType
    {
        using Type = T;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct ElementType<T, false>
    {
        using Type = typename T::value_type;
    };
}
```

I've found out reading a little bit that, this is called partial specialization in c++, and I think it's pretty clear, but there is a thing i do not understand, in the first template there is that `bool` initialized, what is doing?

Thanks to everyone that will be answering!

Comment: That's a default argument, used when the instantiation omits an explicit argument. E.g. `ElementType<int>` is a shorthand for `ElementType<int, std::is_floating_point<int>::value>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this function declaration:

```
void frob(float f, bool g = true) {
    // ...
}
```

As you might know, you can drop parameter name from declarations:

```
void frob(float f, bool = true) {
    // ...
}
```

You can also set the default value using an expression. This is equivalent as the previous example:

```
void frob(float f, bool = std::is_floating_point<float>::value) {
    // ...
}
```

Then, let's add a simple template for the sake of the exercise:

```
template<typename T>
void frob(T f, bool = std::is_floating_point<T>::value) {
    // ...
}
```

Technically, you could move parameters to be template parameters, if you know them at compile time:

```
template<typename T, bool = std::is_floating_point<T>::value>
void frob(T f) {
    // ...
}
```

Now it's beginning to look like your own template declaration isn't it?

---

Now that you understand the syntax, let's see how it's useful with partial specialization.

Imagine you're the compiler and you expand the template instantiation of `ElementType` for `float` and `std::integral_constant<int, 0>`:

```
template<>
struct ElementType<float, std::is_floating_point<float>::value> { ... };

template<>
struct ElementType<
    std::integral_constant<int, 0>,
    std::is_floating_point<int>::value
> { ... };
```

Expands the constants, you get this:

```
template<>
struct ElementType<float, true> { ... };

template<>
struct ElementType<std::integral_constant<int, 0>, false> { ... };
```

Now that you expanded this, you see that you have both true and false as the second parameter. You pick the specialization for each:

```
template<>
struct ElementType<float, true> { using Type = float; };

template<>
struct ElementType<std::integral_constant<int, 0>, false> {
    // int
    using Type = typename std::integral_constant<int, 0>::value_type;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like a functions can take default argument, template can have default parameters.

```
int foo(int a = 5) { ... }

foo(7) // a = 7
foo()  // a = 5
```

The equivalent template example would be

```
template <int I = 5>
int bar() { ... }

bar<10>() // I = 10
bar()     // I = 5
```

In your example the name for the parameter was also left out, which is a common practice if the template parameter is only used to select a partial specialization. We don't need it's name since we never refer to it. We just need it to have a certain value/type.